# Trouble with dreamweaver templates and libraries

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I'm currently in the process of redesigning a website, and I'm using Dreamweaver templates and libraries to maintain a consistent look on each page.

I've gotten to the point where I'm almost finished with the site, and wanting feedback from other people. A way to do this is copy the site over to another drive that is accessible to others in the company I'm working in. The problem is, I copied (ctrl + a) & (ctrl + c) and pasted all files into another folder (on another drive)... and when I go to edit the template and library files in Dreamweaver, they do not update their child-pages. The change is just saved to the .dwt file.

I went back into my other drive (that I had initially made the website in), and updated something on the template page, and a thing pops up and goes through the process of updating each of the child pages. This is what I want in the other drive.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on with copying the files to another drive, that makes it not update?

Comment: consider not using dreamweaver

Comment: My whole site is built using dreamweaver. Are you suggesting that I start over?

Comment: maybe the problem is that the paths are not the same

Comment: Updating the original file will not update the files in other drives unless you are using some kind of version control, you will have to update all the copied files manually. Dreamweaver is fine to use, it just depends on how you use it, I personally use it but I still hand-roll my code so I don't run into any issues with it making a mess of my code.

Comment: Look for a tutorial on Dreamweaver templates. I don't think I've used them since high school, but you need to (do something like) set up a "new site" in Dreamweaver that points to the copied folder.

Comment: @MCSI the paths are the same.

Comment: @thirtydot I tried doing that, but the problem is that it is one folder inside of another website that is already set up as a site in Dreamweaver. Therefore, it won't let me set up another "Site" inside of another "Site".

Comment: Unfortunately, that was the limit of my knowledge on Dreamweaver templates :)

Answer (score 2):

You can manually launch the update dialogue from Modify > Template > Update pages.

If that does not recognise that the page you updated has children it will likely be an issue because of the path of the files. If this is the case I would recommend you manage it as a new 'site' in Dreamweaver, but to do so I would export the original in the manage dialogue to a .ste file, then import it back into DW

Which version of DW are you using? I can set up a site within a site on mine

Comment: The paths weren't the issue. It was that the other "Site" that I set up on the other drive didn't necessarily know that I was even using a template. I found this out by trying to make a new page from template (didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When I copied the folders over to the other drive, Dreamweaver wasn't recognizing the template file (Template/content.dwt) as a template of the site.

What I did: File > Save as Template... and saved over the template file that was in the folder. The child pages updated after that. Thanks to everyone who tried to help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but I solved, problem is with the path, if you have a look at the #begininglibraryitem "/your path.. you can see wrong path, but it should has began with "/your website name or folder name/libarary/...

Just ctrl+f and find replace entire website with. "Match case" option to replace then for a test, change your library and update you can see all pages :)

I think it cause by wrong cash, I dont know the reason but I got how to solve

;)